# Is the set of reduced Residues the same as the set of units?

Tags: number-theory, reduced-residue-system

I am struggling with the concept of Units and the Reduced set of residues. 
I know that a unit is defined to be an element $(a)$ s.t there exists and inverse element $\hat{a}$. where $\hat{a} * a = 1$. and that an extension of this definition is that $\gcd(a,m) = 1$. 
But I also have the definition of the reduced set of residues (mod(m)) as being all the elements where $\gcd(a,m) = 1$.

So does this mean that the set of units $U_m$ is the same as the $RsR_m$ ?

Comment: Yes, they are the same, at least for $m\gt 1$. *Reduced set of residues* is old-fashioned number-theoretic language, while *units* is newer.

Comment: Ah ok that makes A lot of sense! The course I am currently studying introduces $RsR$ first and then talks about Units later. Perhaps the lecturer didn't want to call them $units$ until we had studied that part of the course.

Comment: *Units* is a more abstract concept.

Comment: I was reading your post again, and saw what is kind of an inaccuracy. A reduced set of residues modulo $m$ is a collection of numbers $a$ such that (i) any $a$ in the collection is relatively prime to $m$ **and** (ii) no two numbers in the collection are congruent modulo $m$.